# How can I replicate a RPC firewall entry using New-NetFirewallRule in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, tcp, rpc, powershell-5.0, windows-firewall

I'm working on a deployment script for Windows Server 2012R2 that has to replicate some firewall enrties. The New-NetFirewallRule cmdlet works fine for simple rules but I'm not able to make this custom one work through powershell :

[Rule I'm trying to replicate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XS4Q2.png)

According to [Technet documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/jj554908(v=wps.630).aspx) :

> If the Protocol parameter value is TCP or UDP, then the acceptable
>   values for this parameter are:
>  
>   -- Port range: 0 through 65535.
>  
>   -- Port number: 80. 
>   -- Keyword: PlayToDiscovery or Any.  
> If the Protocol parameter value is ICMPv4 or ICMPv6, then the acceptable values for this parameter
>   are: 
>   -- An ICMP type, code pair: 0, 8. 
>   -- Type and code: 0 through 255. 
>   -- Keyword: Any. 
> If the Protocol parameter is not specified, then the acceptable values for this parameter are: RPC, RPCEPMap, Teredo,
>   IPHTTPSIn, IPHTTPSOut, or Any.

So I can't figure how to define a rule that uses Protocol=TCP and Local Port="RPC Dynamic Ports". Could anyone throw some light here? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that specifying `"RPC"` as the parameter value for `-LocalPort` and `"TCP"` for `-Protocol` parameter will create a rule with the values you are looking for.

Example:

```
New-NetFirewallRule -Name 'Name' -DisplayName 'Name' -Group 'Group' -Profile Domain -Direction Inbound -Action Allow -EdgeTraversalPolicy Block -Protocol 'TCP' -LocalPort 'RPC'
```

Comment: Thanks @jkdba, I've tested the rule and it works like a charm.

Comment: @hairowski awesome, glad it worked, I needed the solution too at one point.